# Show only min and max values on x.axis of ggplot with geom_errorbarh

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create graphs that compare certain values against a fixed min and max values (same as you get on lab test results for example).

Using "geom_errorbarh", I partly succeeded in doing so, but got stuck when I tried to display only those fixed min and max values on the graph:
I tried to use "scale_x_continuous" with fixed breaks, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work as expected on some of the graphs, as can be seen in the image below (in red circles).
[image]

And here is the code I used.

```
library(tidyverse)


dat1 <- tibble(
  name = c("energy","protein","fat","carbs"),
  value = c(5000,105,25,187),
  min_value = c(800,30,20,150),
  max_value=c(4000,80,100,300)
)


p <- ggplot(dat1, aes(value, name))

p + geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = max_value, xmin = min_value),
                 size = 1,
                 colour = "#9b9beb",
                 height=0.2)+ 
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free", ncol=1 )+
  xlab(NULL)+ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks =c(dat1$min_value,dat1$max_value))
```

So as @Santiago recommended in the comments I managed to add different scales using ggh4x. Although there might be a better method to do it with a function or purrr, I am too new for this at the moment.

```
# install.packages("ggh4x")
library(ggh4x)

p + geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = max_value, xmin = min_value),
                 size = 1,
                 colour = "#9b9beb",
                 height=0.2)+ 
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free", ncol=1 )+
  xlab(NULL)+ylab(NULL)+
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(
      name == "energy" ~ scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(dat1$min_value[1],dat1$max_value[1])),
      name == "protein" ~ scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(dat1$min_value[2],dat1$max_value[2])),
      name == "fat" ~ scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(dat1$min_value[3],dat1$max_value[3])),
      name == "carbs" ~ scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(dat1$min_value[4],dat1$max_value[4]))
    )
  )
```

Comment: It is because scale_x_continous will set the same breaks for all facets. To have different breaks in each facet you should take a look to ggh4x package https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x